# How to kill a pid based on the result of an if statement

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, debian-wheezy, raspbian

I'm trying to make a program restart if it has only one pid associated to it (it has to have two pid). if it has more than one it is ok, i've tried to write a bash script to do it but I'm struggling to make it work proprely, this is my code so fr, can anyone help me out to achieve my goal?

```
#! /bib/bash
pgrepRes=($(pgrep deluge))
if ["${#pgrepRes[@]}" -ne "2"];
    then
        kill ${pgrepRes[0]};
fi
deluge
```

but I'm getting this result:

[image]

As you can see I checked how many pid are associated with Deluge.

Thanks in advance, I hope I made myself clear enough, otherwise, ask :)

Comment: Try `$(pgrep deluge | wc -l)`. It should give you the number of lines, and `pkill deluge` inside the if statement. Add a space `[  whatever is ]`. Never `[withoutspaces]`

Comment: @Hastur can you modify my code with an answer please? thanks

Comment: When something doesn't work, break it into its constituent parts. Your problem is the lack of whitespace around `[` and `]`. It has nothing to do with invoking `kill`.

Comment: I suppose it is not compliant with your purpose even the `-ne 2`. You should use `-lt 2` _less then_ and not the _not equal_ `-ne`...  You should find useful to _take some inspirations ;)_ from the [Bash Beginners Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some missprints. Try something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
pgrepN=$( pgrep deluge | wc -l )
if [ "$pgrepN" -lt  "2" ]; then
   echo "less then 2"         # pkill deluge
   echo here restart deluge   # restart only if there were less than 2
fi
```

Note that in the shebang (first line) you should not put a space between `#!` and the path of the shell,  with the test operator `[]` you need to put spaces inside the brackets: for example this is `[ OK ]`  this in `[NOT OK]`.
If I properly understand your purpose you want to restart only if there are less than 2 occurrences, so inside the IF statement.

---

**Update**:

```
#!/bin/bash
Time_to_Sleep="5m"                      # Put here the amount of time
DKiller="/tmp/Kill_Deluge_Script.sh"    # Put here the deluge killer script Name

echo "#!/bin/bash"         >  $DKiller  # Creating script that will kill this one
echo "kill $$; sleep 3s; " >> $DKiller  # Passing the command to kill this one
echo "pkill deluge"        >> $DKiller  # Now you can kill deluge too
echo "echo deluge killed... RIP " >>   $DKiller
chmod u+x $DKiller                      # Make the script executable for you

while true 
do
  pgrepN=$( pgrep deluge | wc -l )
  if [ "$pgrepN" -lt  "2" ]; then
     echo "less then 2"         # pkill deluge
     echo here restart deluge   # restart only if there were less than 2
  fi
sleep $Time_to_Sleep
done
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! thanks a lot! my next task now is to attach it to a cron job that runs every 5 minutes!

Comment: I saved the script in a .sh file and edited the crontab (via crontab-e) and set it to be excecuted every 5 minutes, i also give the chmod 775 permission to be executed but seems to doesn't work in this way... if i copy and paste the script straight into the shell it works fine.. I know that crontab run properly...any idea?

Comment: Since I suppose you have not to run deluge each time, but once you ran you want it will be up, I propose to avoid to touch the _crontab_, and to include the above script in a never ending loop, with a `sleep 5m` inside the loop and with an `echo "kill $$ > /tmp/Kill_Deluge_Script.sh"` and `echo "pkill deluge" >> /tmp/Kill_Deluge_Script.sh` before the loop itself so that when you want you can kill Deluge...

Comment: I can figure out how can implement what  you wrote...can you hel me out editing the above code?

Comment: @FabioEnne You should try and say where you stop. BTW before do your attempt and after check if it works (I didn't).